# Debugging if UTF-8 decoding is done correctly?

Tags: java, utf-8, tcp

We have a Java code talking to external system over TCP connections with xml messages encoded in UTF-8.

The message received begin with '?'. SO the XML received is

```
?<begin>message</begin>
```

There is a real doubt if the first character is indeed '?'. At the moment, we cannot ask the external system if/what.

The code snippet for reading the stream is as below.

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    int readByte = reader.read();
    if (readByte <= 0) {
       inputStream.close();
    }
    builder.append((char) readByte);
```

We are currently trying to log the raw bytes  `int readByte = inputStream.read()`. The logs will take few days to be received.

In the mean time, I was wondering how we could ascertain at our end if it was truly a '?' and not a decoding issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect strongly you have a [byte-order-mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of your doc. That won't render as a valid character, and consequently could appear as a question mark. Can you dump the raw bytes out and check for that sequence ?

Comment: @Brian - other than logging the `int` returned by `inputStream.read()` how else could we dump the raw bytes? -Thanks.

Comment: Also, if it was a BOM, shouldn't we have had 3 ?'s

Comment: @Rohit - No.  The BOM is 3 bytes (when UTF-8 encoded) that represents a single Unicode code-point.  It decodes as one Java `char` ... therefore one question mark.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to boil down to this:

> Can we ascertain the real value of the first byte of the message without actually looking at it.

The answer is "No, you can't".  (Obviously!)

...

However, if you could intercept the TCP/IP traffic from the external system with a packet sniffer (aka traffic monitoring tool), then dumping the first byte or bytes of the message would be simple ... requiring no code changes.

---

> Is logging the int returned by inputStream.read() the correct way to to analyse the bytes received. Or does the word length of the OS or other environment variables come into picture.

The [`InputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) method returns either a single (unsigned) byte of data (in the range 0 to  255 inclusive) or `-1` to indicate "end of stream".  It is not sensitive to the "word length" or anything else.

In short, provided you treat the results appropriately, calling `read()` should give you the data you need to see what the bytes in the stream really are.

Comment: We dont have the option to use a packet snipper, but can do code changes.

Comment: Probably I have not phrased my question correctly. Is logging the `int` returned by `inputStream.read()` the correct way to to analyse the bytes received. Or does the word length of the OS or other environment variables come into picture.